# Pytesseract does not see Tesseract on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to recognize text from an image, but on running the script, an error pops up

```
raise TesseractNotFoundError()
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.
```

Code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('1.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

print(text)
```

Ubuntu 22.04

I am running the code in PyCharm

Tesseract itself is installed via the terminal command:

```
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Write `tesseract --version`  in your terminal. If you get `bash: tesseract : command not found` that means you need to add tesseract to PATH. When you add an executable to PATH, generally, you make it accessible from anywhere.

Comment: added the tesseract path to the PATH variable. In the terminal tesseract works. But when I run the script in Pycharm I get an error

Comment: echo $PATH    
/home/tim/.local/bin:/home/tim/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin/tesseract:/usr/include/tesseract:/usr/share/man/man1:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

Comment: @ТимурСеменеев try this in your program: `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"full path to the exe file"` . What you basically do is explicitly point where the tesseract executable is located.

Comment: How do I know where the tesseract executable file is located on Ubuntu?

Comment: @ТимурСеменеев try `whereis tesseract` or `which tesseract` in your terminal.

Comment: @ТимурСеменеев if you installed tesseract with the command you mentioned above (`sudo apt install tesseract-ocr`) then the path should be `/usr/bin/tesseract`. I just wanted to show you how you can easily find the path of executables with the two commands above.